# Boot issues in a P2V, is there a way to fix?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a machine that i have to virtualize, so i used the disk2vhd program, as the microsoft converter tool, was not working for me. I don't know why, at some point the convertion always hanged up, and didn't finish.

Anyway, when i got the VHD, i attached that vhd to a local hyperv server, then fix some drivers issues and run the sysprep application.

Today i successfuly uploaded the vhd to azure and created an image of it. But after turning on the machine i get a 0x0000007B bsod, i got that bsod as well when i hocked the machine to my local hyperv, in which i've executed a fixmbr and fix the issue. But as far as i know, i can't do that on azure server, right?

Is there anything that i can do to fix that issue?

Regards.

Comment: What is the OS you are trying to migrate?

Comment: Hi Alex, is a windows 7 enterprise edition.

Comment: I suspect that it should not work because client editions are supported only in the MSDN subscriptions (but indeed, that BSOD thing should not be related to that :-). But what is more interesting is how did you fix the issue? That bsod is somehow partitions (AFAIK) connected, so i suspect that there was something wrong with the P2V process itself.

Comment: yes, i know, i had that issue with my personal pc when i changed my sata from ide mode to ahci mode....
but here, we don't have anything like that... ok, will try the microsoft converter again.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? I suspect there can be a problem with the sysprep process - what option did you choose in sysprep?

Comment: Hi, no i didn't. I have followed this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/